# How do i make a user enter their password to logout. Parse/Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, logout

I want to make it so when a user clicks on logout button, They must enter their password to be able to logout.

Using parse and swift. How should i go about this?

Should i, segue from logout button to a new viewcontroller requesting the password entry?

**OR**

is it possible to have a pop-up with a text box that requests the password of the currentUser?

Comment: I'm curious to hear why you want to add this feature.

Comment: Building a product that is B2B, Specific to that Business. This way no one can log the app out or add things to it without placing their password in a few places.

Comment: @Carl using it as a security measure

Answer (score 1):

Use UIAlertController to prompt the user for the password by adding a textfield to your alert ([LKAlertController](https://github.com/lightningkite/LKAlertController) is a good wrapper of this).

There is no local access to your users password but you can attempt to log the existing user in again using `PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground` - if this is successful, call PFUser.logoutInBackgroundWithBlock()

Answer (score 1):

You can show UIAlertController with password text field in it:

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(...)
alertController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField) in
    textField.placeholder = "Password"
    textField.secureTextEntry = true
}

let logoutAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Logout", style: .Default) { (_) in
    let textField = alertController.textFields![0] as UITextField

    logout(textField.text)
}
```

Also in password text field configuration block you can subscribe to `UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification` notification and enable/disable logoutAction depending on entered text.